# Why are there two heaps in a newly created windows process?

Tags: c, winapi, malloc

I discovered this when playing with the standard `malloc` function and calling `HeapWalk` to see the size of the allocated block. Found out that `malloc` does not create blocks in the default process heap but rather in a second heap that I did not create.

Why are there two heaps? Even without calling `malloc` the process still has two heaps and the second one is not empty. This is the result of `HeapWalk` on the second heap without any call to `malloc` or `HeapAlloc`.

[image: Blocks in the second Heap]

Also because of this behaviour of `malloc` another question crossed my mind. Is it correct to allocate memory on the default process heap? I never created a new heap for casual programs and did `HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), ...)` but is this practice harmful or bad in any way?

This is the code i used for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MAX_HEAP_COUNT 10
INT APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    HANDLE hHeaps[MAX_HEAP_COUNT];
    DWORD dwHeaps;

    dwHeaps = GetProcessHeaps(MAX_HEAP_COUNT, hHeaps);

    LPVOID lpDummyBlocks[20];
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        lpDummyBlocks[i] = malloc(rand()%1000+1);


    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwHeaps; i++)
    {
        SIZE_T cbSize = HeapCompact(hHeaps[i], IGNORE);
        printf("Largest free block in heap %lu is %lu bytes.\n", i, cbSize);


        PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY phe;
        phe.lpData = NULL;

        DWORD dwTotalBlocks = 0;

        while(HeapWalk(hHeaps[i], &phe))
        {
            printf("Found a block at address [%p]", phe.lpData);
            printf("    Block size: %lu", phe.cbData);

            for(DWORD i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                if (phe.lpData == lpDummyBlocks[i])
                {
                    printf("    This is DummyBlock%lu", i);
                    break;
                }

            dwTotalBlocks++;
            printf("\n");

        }

        printf("Total blocks: %lu. \n\n", dwTotalBlocks);
    }

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        free(lpDummyBlocks[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I played with the second heap a little bit more and noticed a strange behaviour. I am not sure if my `GetHeapInfo` function is correct but i think thats what [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-process_heap_entry) said about the `.cbData` field of the `PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY` structure.

```
struct tagHEAP_INFO
{
    DWORD dwBlockCount;
    DWORD dwTotalOverhead;
    DWORD dwTotalBlockSize;
};
typedef struct tagHEAP_INFO HEAP_INFO, *LPHEAP_INFO;

WINBOOL APIENTRY GetHeapInfo(HANDLE hHeap, LPHEAP_INFO lpHeapInfo)
{
    // error checking ...
    // ...
    // return FALSE;

    PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY phe;
    phe.lpData = NULL;

    lpHeapInfo->dwBlockCount = 0;
    lpHeapInfo->dwTotalBlockSize = 0;
    lpHeapInfo->dwTotalOverhead = 0;

    while(HeapWalk(hHeap, &phe))
    {
        lpHeapInfo->dwBlockCount++;
        lpHeapInfo->dwTotalBlockSize += phe.cbData;
        lpHeapInfo->dwTotalOverhead += phe.cbOverhead;
    }

    DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
    if (dwLastError == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
        return TRUE;

    Beep(1000, 1000); // well, its easier this way :)
    return FALSE;
}
```

With this function i counted the total bytes allocated at the beginning of the process, after allocating some blocks and after freeing them. This is the strange result (and i checked it and its not an overflow):

[image: Heap diagnostic]

Adding to this, i made the same test with the default process heap. I got strange results here too, this time also the block count did not match (and i checked that all the blocks were allocated).

[image]

Am i misinterpreting this? I am using `HeapWalk` the way this example ([enumerating a heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/enumerating-a-heap)) is showing. This time i only used `HeapAlloc` for allocation.

Comment: Unless you have very specific requirements (e.g. a short-lived heap that gets repeatedly created and deleted, a heap with a set maximum size, a heap that doesn't require synchronization, etc.) it's perfectly fine to use the process heap.

Comment: It is not uncommon for a memory allocation library to use a dedicated heap that it owns and has full control over.  As for your question, you don't know how the OS decides to use heaps internally, so it shouldn't be surprising that there is more than 1 heap in use. Maybe the OS decides to use a dedicated heap for some specialized work.

Comment: Or there could be a force-loaded DLL that creates its own heap for whatever reason.

Comment: It's not hard to imagine that the C runtime library implementation might want/need to create some objects before initializing malloc and thus chooses to use a separate heap.  Still, it would be interesting to learn who/what/why about the second heap.

Comment: There might be a dedicated heap for small allocations below a certain size, for example.